# Cómo simplificar este bloque de código?

Tags: javascript

He realizado el código que necesitaba he ido puliendo y  reduciendo código en la medida de lo posible, pero aún así lo veo muy basto el código a ver si me pueden ayudar a hacer el funcionamiento de una manera más simple.

Básicamente es sacar de una string las mayúsculas, minúsculas y números sacar el valor existente de cada uno para después mediante if poner condicionales cuando ese valor suceda if(mayus >10) return console.log("No puedes usar tantas mayúsculas.");

```js
var str = "abecedario ABECEDARIO 12345";
for(var i = 0, len = str.length, mayus=0, ch; i < len; ++i)
{
 ch = str.charAt(i);
 if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') ++mayus;
}
for(var i = 0, len = str.length, minus=0, ch; i < len; ++i)
{
 ch = str.charAt(i);
 if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') ++minus;
}
for(var i = 0, len = str.length, nume=0, ch; i < len; ++i)
{
 ch = str.charAt(i);
 if(ch >= '1' && ch <= '9') ++nume;
}
var result = mayus-minus;

console.log("Mayús:" + mayus);
console.log("Minus:" + minus);
console.log("Mayús menos Minus:" + result);
console.log("Número:" + nume);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `expresiones regulares` para buscar los valores que necesites y luego sacas el `lenght` para contar el número de caracteres.

Con `match` buscas las coincidencias exactas de la expresión regular que implementes.

Te dejo el ejemplo:

```js
var str = 'abecedari ABECEDARIO 12345';

var mayus = (str.match(/[A-Z]/g) || []).length; 
var minus = (str.match(/[a-z]/g) || []).length; 
var num = (str.match(/[0-9]/g) || []).length; 

console.log("Mayus:" + mayus);
console.log("Minus:" + minus);
console.log("Num:" + num);
```

Comment: Cuanta razón, me había complicado sin más me ha servido tu sugerencia se ve más limpio.